# Dropzone - Simulate upload for certain files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone to do a image check and tell the user if the resolution is good enough for production.

When files are in RAW format (dng, cr2, orf, etc), I want them to be automatically APPROVED (as if they where uploaded) but WITHOUT actually uploading them (RAW files are large and would take too long to upload).

Basically what I mean is that the file would stay in the list with a check-mark but would not be sent to php. Is this possible?

Currently I'm trying to refuse those files based on their type and then programmatically change them to "success". But I can't seem to find how.

```
var counter = 0;
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
    if(file.type == "image/cr2"){
        myDropzone.files[counter].accepted = false;
    }
    counter++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dropzone is going to identify the file type of those formats, but you can check if the filename contains the extension you want, here an example:

```
var formats = ['.orf', '.cr2', '.dng'];

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = $('#yourDropzoneId').dropzone({
    accept: function (file, done) {
        var extension = '.' + file.name.toLowerCase().split('.').slice(-1)[0];
        if (formats.indexOf(extension) >= 0) {
            done('OK');
            $('.dz-preview').last().toggleClass('dz-error dz-success');
        }
        else {
            done();
        }
    }
});
```

In this example the files with a extension specified in the array will be rejected but then is going to simulate a success, the other files with a different extension will be uploaded.